# Plz help! Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection...(done - 0.0.2.0:3)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, relays, bridge

Tried all the "built-in" bridges (fte, meek...etc) as well as custom ones...no go.

It was working fine for over a year. Just recently it started doing this. I'm not an expert, just a basic computer user, or myabe "a little" more than the average user - so layman's terms would be much appreciated.

Any point in the right direction? Thanks in adavnce!

[image]

```
12/29/2016 15:10:54 PM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:03 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:03 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:03 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:03 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/29/2016 15:11:03 PM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
12/29/2016 15:11:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/29/2016 15:11:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:23 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/29/2016 15:11:23 PM.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
12/29/2016 15:11:34 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:34 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:34 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:11:34 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/29/2016 15:11:41 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
12/29/2016 15:12:41 PM.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 7; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3) 
12/29/2016 15:12:41 PM.900 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
12/29/2016 15:12:41 PM.900 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12/29/2016 15:14:11 PM.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/29/2016 15:14:11 PM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/29/2016 15:14:11 PM.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on        127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: What happens when you load https://a0.awsstatic.com/ or https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ in a normal browser?

Comment: @canonizingironize - They load. Anything particular i should be looking for?

Comment: No, those are the "front" domains used by `meek-amazon` and `meek-azure`. To a censor, they shouldn't be able to easily distinguish between a normal visit to that site and a connection to one of the `meek` endpoints. Unless they're doing more advanced (expensive/slow) analysis...do you know what kind of censorship is in place?

Comment: @canonizingironize - I have noo clue. Don't even know if censorship is the issue.

Comment: It's either censorship or a horribly slow connection (which could also be a sign of censorship).